# Selenium webdriver server does not response after my win10 computer was locked for over 10 mins

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

my code is like this:

```
    def browser_is_quit(self):
        try:
            if self.browser is not None:
                _ = self.browser.current_url
                return False
            return True
        except NoSuchWindowException:
            self.browser = None
            return True
    def open_url(url):
        if self.browser_is_quit():
            self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            self.options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
            self.options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
            self.options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
            self.options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir={}'.format(CHROME_USER_CACHE))
            self.options.binary_location = CHROME_EXE
            self.service = ChromeService(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER)
            self.options.add_argument('--app={}'.format(url))
            self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=self.service, options=self.options)
        else:
            self.browser.get(url)
```

I open the url on the chrome browser, but when i lock my computer for over almost 10 mins, the webdriver server does not response. when i request `self.browser.get(url)`,the selenium request GET http://localhost:56639/session/f147cb1da96861998b67e274a5c9fccb/url {} to webdriver server,but it does not response. Is session timeout or webdriver server was dead?

I want webdriver server is alive for always. how to fix this issue?

Comment: where is the rest of the code.  there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)